# Did the Tsalot HaAron in Shemot 25:14 refer to the sidewalls (left & right of Keruvim)?

Tags: shemot-exodus, ark-aron-kodesh

**Did the צַלְעֹ֣ת הָאָרֹ֑ן Tsalot HaAron in [Shemot 25:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) refer to the sidewalls (left & right of Keruvim)?**

- HaKohanim הַכֹּהֲנִים֙ The-Priests in [Devarim 31:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0) (Deuteronomy 31:9) were required to carry HaAron הָאָרֹ֑ן (The-Ark) by lifting the poles kept in the rings attached to צַלְעֹ֣ת הָאָרֹ֑ן Tsalot HaAron [Shemot 25:14]. The צַלְעֹ֣ת Tsalot (side walls) refers to the “Length” of HaAron הָאָרֹ֑ן The-Ark, at the left & right of the Keruvim (not behind them). - Correct? -
- 4 Kohathite shoulders support the 4 corners of HaAron. The poles of HaAron would be parallel along the 2.5 cubits Length. The pole (left of the Keruv) rests on the right-shoulders of Kohathites (standing to the left of the Keruv). The pole (right of the Keruv) rests on the left-shoulders of the Kohathites (standing to the right of the Keruv). - Correct?
- HaAron was traditionally carried on the shoulders of Benei Qehat בְנֵ֥י קְהָ֖ת the Sons of Kohath (Kohathites) stated וְלִבְנֵ֥י קְהָ֖ת לֹ֣א נָתָ֑ן כִּֽי־עֲבֹדַ֤ת הַקֹּ֙דֶשׁ֙ עֲלֵהֶ֔ם בַּכָּתֵ֖ף יִשָּֽׂאוּ in Numbers / [Bamidbar 7:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.7.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0). - If the Sons of Qehat & HaKohanim were approaching you with HaAron (without the blue wool cloth covering), you would see a Keruv's back bowing to דְבַר־יְ֠הֹוָה the Word of YHVH. - Correct?

Answer (score 3):

> If the Sons of Qehat & HaKohanim were approaching you with HaAron, you would see a Keruv's back bowing to דְבַר־יְ֠הֹוָה the Word of YHVH. - Correct?

No, the *aron* was carried covered with cloth. See Numbers 4:4–15.

Answer (score 0):

> The צַלְעֹ֣ת Tsalot (side walls) refers to the “Length” of HaAron הָאָרֹ֑ן The-Ark, at the left & right of the Keruvim (not behind them). - Correct?

No, the poles were attached along the shorter walls ("width") of the Aron, so that there would be space for two priests to stand between the poles when carrying the Aron. See [Menachot 98a - 98b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Menachot.98b.2?lang=bi). This would presumably mean that each of the poles was behind one of the *keruvim*.

Comment: The poles were definitely on the short sides, but do you know which way the cherubs were situated?

Comment: Four men carried the Aron, based on Menachot 98b.3. Which means 2 men walk (shoulder to shoulder) at 1 end of the "Length" + 2 men walk (shoulder to shoulder) at the other end of the Length. -  Facing forward (shoulder to shoulder) : the man on the right helped carry one pole resting it on his left shoulder & the man on the left helped carry another pole resting it on his right shoulder. - The poles would have to be attached to the sidewalls along the Length of the Aron. - Correct?

Comment: @חִידָה No. The assumption is that they stood between the poles. The man on the right has the pole on his right shoulder, and the man on the left had the pole on his left shoulder. This is how the gemara knows that the poles were along the width of the aron, not the length - there would not be room for two men to fit between the poles if the poles were along the length

Comment: Their shoulders fit under the corners of the Aron. Their entire bodies don't fit under the Aron. - Menachot 98b.2 seems to be perceiving the problematic example.

Comment: @חִידָה I'm afraid I don't understand your last comment

Comment: @msh210 It's not definitive, but the command to make the cherubs משני קצות הכפורת sounds to me like it's talking about the short edges

Comment: 4 Shoulders at 4 corners of the Aron. The poles of Aron are parallel along the Length. The pole (left of the Aron) rests on the right shoulders of Kohathites (standing to the left of the Aron). The pole (right of the Aron) rests on the left shoulders of the Kohathites (standing to the right of the Aron).

Comment: @חִידָה You keep on assuming this, but that's not at all what the gemara in Menachot says. It's black and white there that the poles are parallel along the width, and that the carriers stood between the poles (so left pole on left shoulder and right pole on right shoulder).